# Applying actionBarStyle clears ActionBar Style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-styles

I am attempting to apply a standard style across both my `Toolbar`s and window level `ActionBar`s I have been using the following code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pallet_aqua_rich</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pallet_aqua_rich_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pallet_orange_vivid</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/krub</item>

    <!-- Custom Application Theme attrs -->
    <item name="appColorPrimary">@color/pallet_aqua_rich</item>
    <item name="appColorPrimaryDark">@color/pallet_aqua_rich_dark</item>
    <item name="appColorPrimaryOpacity80">#DE017d69</item>
    <item name="appColorSecondary">@color/pallet_orange_vivid</item>
    <item name="appColorSecondaryDark">@color/pallet_orange_rich</item>
    <item name="appColorSecondaryOpacity50">#80ea6430</item>

    <item name="appColorSecondaryLight">#EB7242</item>
    <item name="appColorSecondaryLighter">#F19C7B</item>
    <item name="appColorSecondaryLightStatusBar">#D6683C</item>

    <!-- Toolbar Styling -->
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>

    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>

    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_chevron_left</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_chevron_left</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/krub_semi_bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>

    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText</item>

    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/krub_semi_bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

The above styles work perfectly for all my XML based `Toolbar`s, but I'm experiencing issues when attempting to apply the same styles to a window built `ActionBar`.

This is the desired result and working example of an XML based Toolbar:

[image: XML Toolbar]

However as soon as I try to replicate the toolbar styling in the Window's `ActionBar` using:

```
    <!-- Window ActionBar Styling -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
```

within `AppTheme`, this is the result:

[image: Problem Example]

As you can see faintly, the correct `homeAsUpIndicator` and `titleTextStyle` have been applied as required, but there is no background. If I remove the `actionBarStyle` item, it applies the background but then fails to apply the `titleTextStyle` and `homeAsUpIndicator`:

[image: Half way house]

Can anyone suggest why this is occurring and suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I overlooked the default `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` carrying:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar" parent="">
    <item name="background">@null</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@null</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@null</item>
</style>
```

Changing `AppTheme.ActionBar`'s parent to `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid` fixes the issue.